# Returning largest number from an array using an int function not printing value

Tags: arrays, c, printf, return-value, function-definition

I am attempting to create a small program that receives an array and returns the largest number from the array. I was able to create a program using a function with the initializer "void", but do not understand why I can't do the same with a different function using "int".

I get the error "incompatible pointer types returning 'int *(int *, int *)' from a function with result type 'int *'" when using the function `int largestNum(int *length,int numberArr[])`. Any explanation is appreciated.

**Input:**
Element 0 - 23
Element 1 - 12
Element 2 - 34

**Output:** 34

Function using void:

```
void largestNum(int *length,int numberArr[]){

 int largestNumber = numberArr[0];

 for(int x = 1;x < *length;x++){
   if (numberArr[x] > largestNumber)
   largestNumber = numberArr[x];
  }
  printf("%d", largestNumber);
 }


int main(){

 int numbersArr[100];
 int input;
 int num;
 int count = 0;
 
 printf("Input total number of elements (1-100): ");
 scanf("%d", &num);

 for(int x = 0; x < num; x++){
   printf("Element %d - ", count);
   scanf("%d", numbersArr + x);
   count++;
 }


 largestNum(&count, numbersArr);

 return 0;
 }
```

Function using int:

```
int largestNum(int *length,int numberArr[]){

 int largestNumber = numberArr[0];

 for(int x = 1;x < *length;x++){
   if (numberArr[x] > largestNumber)
   largestNumber = numberArr[x];
 }
 return largestNumber;
} 


int main(){

 int numbersArr[100];
 int input;
 int num;
 int count = 0;

 printf("Input total number of elements (1-100): ");
 scanf("%d", &num);

 for(int x = 0; x < num; x++){
   printf("Element %d - ", count);
   scanf("%d", numbersArr + x);
   count++;
 }


  largestNum(&count, numbersArr);

  printf(largestNum);

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: <O/T> no reason to pass the array length as a pointer, just pass the value.

Comment: Use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` and fix everything the compiler complains about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`largestNum` is a function declared like

```
int largestNum(int *length,int numberArr[]);
```

So in this call

```
printf(largestNum);
```

the function designator is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `int( int *, int * )` but the function printf expects the first argument of the type `char *`. That is the above call of `printf` does not make a sense. You need to output the returned value of the function. For example

```
printf("%d\n", largestNum(&count, numbersArr) );
```

Pay attention to that in general the function is incorrect. It can invoke undefined behavior when the value of the expression `*length` is equal to `0`.

Also there is no great sense to pass the first argument by reference.
And as the array is not being changed within the function it should be declared with the qualifier const.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
size_t largestNum( const int numberArr[], size_t n )
{
    size_t largestNumber = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( numberArr[largestNumber] < numberArr[i] )
        {
            largestNumber = i;
        }
    }
    
    return largestNumber;
}
```

And the function can be called like

```
size_t pos = largestNum( numbersArr, count );
printf("%d\n", numbersArr[pos] );
```

To check an error when the second parameter was specified equal to 0 you can write

```
size_t pos = largestNum( numbersArr, count );
if ( pos != count ) printf("%d\n", numbersArr[pos] );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm assuming you meant "%d" instead of "%zu" inside of the printf statement?

Comment: @SimTim124 As I declared the return type as size_t then to output an object of this type you have to use the conversion specifier %zu.

Comment: I see. Any particular reason why I am getting the warning "format specifies type 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
printf("%zu\n", numbersArr[pos] );" when I run the code with %zu but not when I replace it with %d?

Comment: @SimTim124 Oh, it is my typo. As we are outputting an element of the array that has the type int then indeed you need to use the conversion specifier %d. I have  updated my answer.:)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the value in a variable like:

```
a = largestNum(&count, numberArr);
printf("%d", a);
```

Or you can just call the function in the printf

```
printf("%d", largestNum(&count, numberArr))
```